# Parsing the JSON response returned by MediaWiki OpenSearch API

Tags: java, json, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, opensearch

I have used the OpenSearch API as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457977/searching-wikipedia-using-api).

The result I get, as shown in a solution in that page, is of this form:

```
[
   "Malleshwaram",
   ["Malleshwaram"],
   [""],
   ["https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Malleshwaram"]
]
```

Now I have collected this in a **JSONArray object (org.json)**. But I am unable to parse it since there is *no key* in these key value pairs. How do I get the elements by their indices?

I just wanted to separate these elements and store them in different string arrays.

Comment: It's hard to know what you are asking when you are not even specifying the language. Are you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript ?

Comment: I had added java as a tag when I created this post :) Anyways, I solved my problem, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The sample JSON you posted is a single-dimensional array of mixed data types: a string, and three string arrays.  It might be easier to make a two-dimensional array of Objects, and use appropriate accessors to return the values you're looking for, implemented in a way that accounts for what the possible JSON responses could be if there is more than one URL returned, etc.